# Wireframe cube display matrix values Pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I have the follow code, I have created a rotated cube and I want to display in every corner, point, the values as the picture because I can't see the points to create, for example, an other cube next to this points.[image]

I run this script in Windows XP, Python 2.7 the code is below

```
        import sys, math, pygame

        class Point3D:
            def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0):
                self.x, self.y, self.z = float(x), float(y), float(z)

            def rotateX(self, angle):
                """ Rotates the point around the X axis by the given angle in degrees. """
                rad = angle * math.pi / 180
                cosa = math.cos(rad)
                sina = math.sin(rad)
                y = self.y * cosa - self.z * sina
                z = self.y * sina + self.z * cosa
                return Point3D(self.x, y, z)

            def rotateY(self, angle):
                """ Rotates the point around the Y axis by the given angle in degrees. """
                rad = angle * math.pi / 180
                cosa = math.cos(rad)
                sina = math.sin(rad)
                z = self.z * cosa - self.x * sina
                x = self.z * sina + self.x * cosa
                return Point3D(x, self.y, z)

            def rotateZ(self, angle):
                """ Rotates the point around the Z axis by the given angle in degrees. """
                rad = angle * math.pi / 180
                cosa = math.cos(rad)
                sina = math.sin(rad)
                x = self.x * cosa - self.y * sina
                y = self.x * sina + self.y * cosa
                return Point3D(x, y, self.z)

            def project(self, win_width, win_height, fov, viewer_distance):
                """ Transforms this 3D point to 2D using a perspective projection. """
                factor = fov / (viewer_distance + self.z)
                x = self.x * factor + win_width / 2
                y = -self.y * factor + win_height / 2
                return Point3D(x, y, 1)

        class Simulation:
            def __init__(self, win_width = 640, win_height = 480):
                pygame.init()

                self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))
                pygame.display.set_caption("3D Wireframe Cube Simulation (http://codeNtronix.com)")

                self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

                self.vertices = [
                    Point3D(-1,1,-1),
                    Point3D(1,1,-1),
                    Point3D(1,-1,-1),
                    Point3D(-1,-1,-1),
                    Point3D(-1,1,1),
                    Point3D(1,1,1),
                    Point3D(1,-1,1),
                    Point3D(-1,-1,1)
                ]




                # Define the vertices that compose each of the 6 faces. These numbers are
                # indices to the vertices list defined above.
                self.faces = [(0,1,2,3),(1,5,6,2),(5,4,7,6),(4,0,3,7),(0,4,5,1),(3,2,6,7)]



                self.angleX, self.angleY, self.angleZ = 0, 0, 0

            def run(self):
                """ Main Loop """
                while 1:
                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            sys.exit()

                    self.clock.tick(50)
                    self.screen.fill((0,0,0))

                    # Will hold transformed vertices.
                    t = []


                    for v in self.vertices:
                        # Rotate the point around X axis, then around Y axis, and finally around Z axis.
                        r = v.rotateX(self.angleX).rotateY(self.angleY).rotateZ(self.angleZ)
                        # Transform the point from 3D to 2D
                        p = r.project(self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height(), 256, 4)
                        # Put the point in the list of transformed vertices
                        t.append(p)



                    for f in self.faces:
                        pygame.draw.line(self.screen, (255,255,255), (t[f[0]].x, t[f[0]].y), (t[f[1]].x, t[f[1]].y))
                        pygame.draw.line(self.screen, (255,255,255), (t[f[1]].x, t[f[1]].y), (t[f[2]].x, t[f[2]].y))
                        pygame.draw.line(self.screen, (255,255,255), (t[f[2]].x, t[f[2]].y), (t[f[3]].x, t[f[3]].y))
                        pygame.draw.line(self.screen, (255,255,255), (t[f[3]].x, t[f[3]].y), (t[f[0]].x, t[f[0]].y))







                    self.angleX += 1
                    self.angleY += 1
                    self.angleZ += 1

                    pygame.display.flip()

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            Simulation().run()
```

Comment: Update for my question colored Points

    for v in self.vertices:

           # Rotate the point around X axis, then around Y axis, and finally around Z axis.
           r = v.rotateX(self.angleX).rotateY(self.angleY).rotateZ(self.angleZ)
           # Transform the point from 3D to 2D
           p = r.project(self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height(), 256, 4)
           # Put the point in the list of transformed vertices
           t.append(p)
           x, y = int(p1.x), int(p1.y)
           self.screen.fill((255,0,0),(x,y,3,3))